# Python 3.9. Воспроизведение звука с определенной секунды

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, qsound

Подскажите какую библиотеку лучше использовать?
Задачи очень простые: воспроизведение звука с определенного момента и остановка на другом заданном моменте, обрезка звука. Не хотелось бы использовать PyGame для таких простых задач.

Comment: qsound намекает на Qt - затащи QMediaPlayer

Comment: @eri
Не уверен что подойдет, но можно попробовать, тут хотя бы свойство seekable есть. Вообще в PyQt5 не нашел чего-то подходящего.

Comment: setposition - play - поймал сигнал на смену позишн и стоп

Comment: @eri Не, всё же пришлось pygame использовать, там и буфер нарезать можно и звук собирать из отрезков и всё это парой строк кода. Один недостаток, нарезки буфера для wav и ogg, с mp3 прокатывает только воспроизведение.
Спасибо за подсказки ;)

Comment: Так нареж заранее и положи в файл ресурса

Comment: @eri Это программа для создания мультиков, в ней пользователь должен иметь возможность свои звуки вставлять)